# $F$ is closed if and only if $f(F)$ is a closed then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function with the additional property $$F\;\mbox{is a closed subset of }\mathbb{R}\;\iff f(F)\;\mbox{is a closed subset of}\;\mathbb{R}.$$

I would like to prove that $f$ is a surjective map.

(In fact it's an homeomorphism but I am interested to prove the surjectivity only)

I try using that as $\Bbb{R}$ is closed so that $f(\Bbb{R})$ is closed and connected subset of $\Bbb{R}$ so it's a closed interval. But not sure how to eliminate $[a,b]\;;(-\infty,b]\;;[a;\infty).$

Comment: @CameronBuie yeah of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by way of contradiction that $f$ is not surjective, so that by connectedness, $f(\Bbb R)$ is bounded above and/or below.

Suppose it is bounded above, and let $b$ be its supremum. By closedness, $b$ is its maximum, so there exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=b.$ Now, show that $f$ maps one of $(-\infty,x+1)$ and $(x-1,\infty)$ onto $f(\Bbb R),$ contradicting our closedness condition. We similarly obtain a contradiction if it is bounded below.

Comment: Little addition:  in order to say $f(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded below or above, we need to think about connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ and continuity of $f$.

Comment: True. The OP already noticed that, though

Comment: thank you, to prove that that $f$ maps one of (...), we need the continuity of $f$ as well, didn't we ?

Comment: @TheVie: Yes, we do, so that we can have connectedness of both.